# Fijar preguntas en "centro de ayuda"

Tags: discusión, centro-de-ayuda

He visto que en el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) hay varias preguntas "fijadas" con el "pin" para que salgan las primeras.

Me preguntaba si esto es algo que se pueda cambiar y si es así, si sería posible ponérselo a las siguientes preguntas que creo que son las mas usadas:

- [¿Cómo elaboro una buena
  pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y
  verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. [En Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) tenemos fijados otros (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lFL3.png), pero es algo que creo que solo pueden cambiar los CM

Comment: me parece muy buena idea para los que usamos dichas preguntas, otras que se pueden agregar son [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), incluso si es posible [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @the-breaker Esas 3 justo son las que están actualmente "fijas"

Comment: Se lo he comentado a nuestro CM Nicholas y está consultando la posibilidad de hacerlo.

Comment: @x3k_js disculpa, entendí mal, en ese caso no estoy ni en contra ni a favor.

Comment: @the-breaker Mi propuesta no es de quitar las que ya estan "fijas" con el "pin", me parece que están correctamente fijadas. Si no añadir esas 2 que menciono el "pin" para que queden "fijas" también arriba de la lista de modo que las mas usadas queden arriba.

Comment: @x3k_js entiendo, no dije nada de quitar las que ya están, solo creo que no es un problema tan serio.